# how can i understand ,which ember addon version compatibility with ember-cli or node version

Tags: node.js, npm, ember.js, dependencies, version

I have not much experienced in Ember dependency

I have searched but i can not find  which ember addon version compatibility with ember-cli or node version

I can find only this ember-cli node support https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/blob/master/docs/node-support.md

Do I have to experience all , I can only guess version compatibility

For example : 
ember-simple-auth@2.1.0  compatible  with ember-cli 3.x ,
ember-simple-auth@1.1.0  compatible  with ember-cli 2.x

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-simple-auth/v/2.1.0

In the topic "Basic Usage" , i saw the Ember code syntax then this is it

For example  : nodejs v6.x , npm v3.x, ember-cli 2.13 , Let's say it is working 
i want to add "ember-cli-sass" , which version i must choose ?

Is there a way to find out  or  isn't there something like that

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most addons include a compatibility statement in their readme. Such a compatibility statement is generated by [default blueprint for Ember addons](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-addon-output#compatibility). If such a statement exist, you could view the readme for the latest as well as for old versions on GitHub.

If the addon does not document the compatibility explicitly, you could have a look in CI configuration. Most ember addon use Travis as a continuous integration pipeline. The configuration is stored in `.travis.yml` file as part of the source code in repository. It should list the used node versions and the `ember-source` versions the tests are run again. Most ember addons run their tests against some ember versions out of their support range - most likely the LTS versions covered by their compatibility statement.

The supported node version is for most ember addons determined by the used version of Ember CLI. There is a good chance that the addon will work with a specific node version if that version is supported by Ember CLI version used by the addon. Have a look in `package.json` for `ember-cli` package to get the used version.